# how to read the content of the file using Fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to read the content of a file using Fileupload.

For example I want to save the XML file in Database , a user search the file using Fileupload and then click a button to save the content of the file in Database.

I tried this one but doesn't work

```
string s=Fileuploder1.Filecontent.tostring();
```

but no success,Do you have any idea?

Comment: using asp.net? please tag related technology

Comment: This question is extremely broad (close). I recommend you ask only one thing at a time.

Comment: @usr, I see only one question here.

Answer (score 26):

```
string inputContent;
using (StreamReader inputStreamReader = new StreamReader(InputFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    inputContent = inputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream) was required for me to actually read the file

Answer (score -2):

we cannot directly read the file, instead of that we should save it in the project location. using the project file path we can read with the help of stream reader.

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(filePath);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document"), fileName)))
                    {
                        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            strbuild.AppendFormat(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }

                }
```

for more details:http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-read-text-file-using-fileupload-control-in-asp-net-MVC/1245